# Some questions regarding UDDI

Tags: soap, wso2, soa, uddi

Currently, I am learning SOA and come across UDDI. I have several questions around this and hope someone can help:

1. By searching in the Internet I come across some interesting products e.g. WSO2 Governance Registry. Is it an UDDI if I only deploy SOAP services to it? How do people find the services then?
2. I have also come across a product called WSO2 API Manager. It looks like a tool for publishing API/web services. If someone can already find the web services using Governance Registry, what is the use of API Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Governance Registry is more about service metadata management. It is much about design time governance and not much about runtime governance. It is a SOA tool. It supports UDDI through JUDDI but that is not a first class support. WSO2 Governance Registry defines its own database based meta model.

WSO2 API Management is about runtime management of APIs. It comes with design time tools, to help wrap services as APIs to be exposed to the outside world. However, the key functionality is about the runtime monitoring, management, and security of the API calls via the API Gateway.

Comment: Thx for your answer. So, am I correct to say that, as a developer I will build my service and use Governance Registry to help managing the development process. When the service is ready for publication, I will then use API Manager to wrap the service as API and manage the service using API Manager since then?